# Parity account balance not updated

Tags: accounts, testnets, parity, balances, kovan

I'm using parity in ropsten testnet.

My account address is 0x00562e88274Ac44752913955EEEd4CAa939C6abB. On etherscan it says that account balance is 4 ether but on parity it says that "There are no balances associated with this account". any ideas of what could be?
Thanks!